# Meaningful outcome measure

Tags: data-transformation, proportion, scales

I'm conducting a research about deaths due to a certain medication. I know the number of deaths, which is rather small (from 4 to 20 a month) compared to the total of times that the drug was used (~8 million uses a month).

I want to look at the proportion $deaths\space / total \space use$ and how it evolves over time (so far just by using linear regression). However, the proportions are ridiculously low e.g. $0.0000005, 0.00000053$ etc.

I haven't found a way on how to express this quantities so they are more straightforward and meaningful. I was thinking of using another scale or maybe applying some transformation but not sure which is the best way to go! I'd appreciate some suggestions

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The characteristics of your dataset $\vec{X}$ seems such, that it follows a Poissonian distribution, $X \sim Pois(\lambda)$. Thus, I would calculate the point estimator and confidence interval of the rate parameter $\lambda = E[\vec{X}] = Var[\vec{X}]$ and check whether or not it changes with time.

Note that the expectation value of any statistical quantity is insufficient to draw any conclusion about a dataset. You always need the standard deviation of the point estimator as well. A Boxplot would be a convenient way to represent the data.